# Как сделать так чтобы сервер на node js не падал при сохранении файла

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
{
    "landscape": [
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 320,
            "y": 340,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/landscape/ground1.png"
        },
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 720,
            "y": 220,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/landscape/ground1.png"
        },
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 580,
            "y": 540,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/landscape/ground1.png"
        },
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 420,
            "y": 660,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/landscape/ground1.png"
        }
    ],
    "gameObjects": [
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 500,
            "y": 280,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/gameObjects/small_tree.png"
        },
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 600,
            "y": 340,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/gameObjects/small_tree.png"
        },
        {
            "w": 60,
            "h": 60,
            "x": 440,
            "y": 400,
            "texture": "assets/mapTextures/gameObjects/small_tree.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

такой json файлик прилетает на сервер, и он перебирает этот файл, ищет картинку в папке и копирует в папку игровой карты. Проблема в том, что когда элементов много, то сервер падает.

код самого сервера

```
server.post("/save", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    const mapsStorage = path.join(publicPath, 'maps');
    const createDirName = req.query.locname;
    const dir = path.join(mapsStorage, createDirName);
    
    const map = req.body;
    fs.access(dir, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            fs.mkdir(dir, (err) => {
                err && console.log(err);
                fs.writeFile(`${dir}/map.json`, JSON.stringify(map),(err)=>{
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                });
            });
            fs.mkdir(`${dir}/assets`, (err) => { err && console.log(err); return});
        }else{
            fs.writeFile(`${dir}/map.json`, JSON.stringify(map),(err)=>{
                if(err) console.log(err);
            });
        }
    })
    
    for(let piece in map){
        map[piece].map(item=>{
            const imageName = item.texture.match(/([a-z]+\/){3}(.+\.png)/i)[2];
            fs.access(`${dir}/assets/${imageName}`, (err)=>{
                err && fs.copyFileSync(path.join(publicPath, item.texture), `${dir}/assets/${imageName}`, (err)=>{
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        };
                        console.log("file copy");
                    });
            })
        })
        
    }
});
```

Comment: Использую базу данных или что-то для хранения данных, а не просто в файле.

Comment: так мне все равно надо скопировать изображения и перенести в другую новую папку, а сервер падает скорее всего из-за этого

Comment: @Istinnavvine ты коллбеки хорошо освоил?

Comment: в каком плане? Я уже разобрался из-за чего это было

Comment: у тебя тут куча действий, которые должны выполняться последовательно, но в коде они не ждут друг друга. создание каталога `${dir}/assets` не ждёт окончания создания `dir`, файлы копируются не дождавшись создания `${dir}/assets`, весь код в сумме не ждёт когда скопируются файлы. при некоторой нагрузке на диск этот код перестанет работать так "псевдосинхронно", как работает без нагрузки. проверь - поставь в нескольких терминалах генерацию 2гб файла из рандома и попробуй в это же время запустить выполнение программы

Comment: как бы то ни было, если вопрос решён то его стоит закрыть. ну и предыдущий, про загрузку

Comment: то есть лучше выполнять это синхроно?

Comment: нет тут никакого лучше. нужно понимать [как это работает](https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/). важно другое. или ты тут используешь асинхронность nodejs и тогда, чтобы код действительно работал так, как ты ожидаешь, нужно связать все колбеки или _перейти на promises_. или переписать всё на синхронный io (потеряв на блокировке процесса, но прийдя к "код действительно работал так, как ты ожидаешь"). пока обобщённый совет: сделай синхронным, если асинхронность пока тяжела для понимания, потому что код в нынешнем виде преподнесёт кучу непредказуемого поведения

Comment: я понял, спасибо. Просто пока не увижу сам ошибку не пойму что код корявый) Хорошей ночи\дня